# Why are the bars still stacked despite the position set as dodge?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar graph using ggplot2 in R, where the bars are positioned next to each other using `position = "dodge"`.

However, despite setting the position as dodge, the bars are still stacking on top of each other.

I have already restarted RStudio and rerun the entire code, but the issue persists.

I have included my code below as well as the resulting graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Data
df <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C"),
  value1 = c(10, 15, 5),
  value2 = c(8, 12, 3)
)

# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x = category)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = value1, fill = "Value 1"), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = -value2, fill = "Value 2"), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  ylab("Value") +
  labs(fill = "Legend")
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `position = "dodge"` to have effect here, you need to include each of the bars in the same geom. Try pivoting your data first so that all of your y values are in the same column

```
newdat <- pivot_longer(average_trip_time, 
                cols = c("total_average", "member", "casual"), 
                names_to = "y_col", 
                values_to = "val")

ggplot(data = newdat, aes(x = month_name)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = val, fill = y_col), 
stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.10)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you for the help.